# Cannot reference parent table primary key

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys, single-table-inheritance

Here is a simple example of my problem

```
CREATE TABLE parent (
 id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE child (
 name text
) INHERITS (parent);

-- Populating child table
INSERT INTO child (name) VALUES ('Alex');
INSERT INTO child (name) VALUES ('Simba');
INSERT INTO child (name) VALUES ('Jafar');


CREATE TABLE test(
 parentId INTEGER REFERENCES parent (id)
)

-- I checked Alex has id of 1 and it is present in parent table
INSERT INTO test(parentId) VALUES (1);-- This line does not work
```

I geting the following message:
insert into test(parentId) VALUES (1)

> ERROR:  insert or update on table "test" violates foreign key constraint "test_parentid_fkey"
>     DETAIL:  Key (parentid)=(1) is not present in table "parent".

Why do i get this ERROR ?

Comment: You have to insert the value inside the `parent` table with `id=1` as, you are using it in your mapping table. Hence, it throws the error.

Comment: What do you mean by install as I wrote the record with id =1 is present in parent table because child table inhertce it

Comment: Changed it to insert..

Comment: What does 'SELECT * FROM parent` return. Check if it has any value with `id=1`

Comment: [Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-inherit.html#DDL-INHERIT-CAVEATS): "*A serious limitation of the inheritance feature is that indexes (including unique constraints) and foreign key constraints only apply to single tables, not to their inheritance children*"